# NS_NOINTERFACE: Component does not have requested interface [nsIDOMLocation.reload]

Tags: javascript

I get this error doing in my javascript console doing:

```
setTimeout(location.reload, 3000);
```

to reload the page after 3 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, do instead:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload();
}, 3000);
```